# is & in ruby a function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Proc Examples

```
 p = Proc.new { |x| puts x*2 }
[1,2,3].each(&p)
```

The '&' tells ruby to turn the proc into a block

I have the above example and wonder if & is a function taking a proc as an argument?

Also here is the signature of form_for in rails.

```
form_for(record, options = {}, &block)
```

is &block a block turned into proc or the other way around?

Answer (score 3):

> I have the above example and wonder if & is a function taking a proc as an argument?

It's not a function (Ruby doesn't have functions). It's an operator. It is only valid in an argument list, and it "unrolls" a `Proc` object into a block as if it had been passed as a literal block. If the object is not already a `Proc`, it will try to convert it to one by sending it the message `to_proc`.

> is &block a block turned into proc or the other way around?

In this case, `&` is a sigil that is only valid in a parameter list (similar to how a `*` denotes a rest parameter). It "wraps" a literal block that is passed to the message send in a `Proc` object and binds it to the parameter such that it is available inside the method/block body by name. Normally, blocks are anonymous and can only be `yield`ed to implicitly.

Comment: so does it mean '&' can convert literal blocks into proc and vice versa given in a parameter list?

Answer (score 2):

No. `&` is an unary operator that convert proc into block (or otherwise), i.e.

```
def foo
  yield
end

def bar(&block)
  block.call
end

baz = -> { print "baz" }

foo(baz) # => ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
foo(&baz) # => baz

foo(baz) # => ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
foo(&baz) # => baz
```

Comment: -> { print "baz" }
what does '->' do ?

Comment: It in lambda syntax that appeared in 1.9

Comment: Thanks! One more question. Since anything in ruby is an object. Is & an object? and what is its type?

Comment: Not everything in Ruby is na object. Methods, operators and blocks aren't methods.